# How to use the existed sample application to integrate google credentials in the iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gdata

From the below link I download the .zip file it contains some example. In that I played the OAuthSampleTouch application.

```
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/downloads/list
```

This is the file I downloaded :
    gdata-objectivec-client-1.11.0.zip

I gone through it but I am getting confusion how to pass input that is email and password and then how to connect through google form my iphone app.

Newly edited code:
This is code from OAuthSampleTouch example in the class "OAuthSampleRootViewControllerTouch.m" Please refer http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/downloads/list in that OAuthSampleTouch application.

```
- (void)signInToGoogle 
{
  [self signOut];

  NSString *keychainAppServiceName = nil;
  if ([self shouldSaveInKeychain]) 
  {
    keychainAppServiceName = kAppServiceName;
  }

  // For GData applications, the scope is available as
    // NSString *scope = [[service class] authorizationScope];
  NSString *scope = @"http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";

  // ### Important ###
  // GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch is not designed to be reused. Make a new
  // one each time you are going to show it.

  // Display the autentication view.
  GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch *viewController = [[[GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch alloc]
            initWithScope:scope
                 language:nil
           appServiceName:keychainAppServiceName
                 delegate:self
         finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)] autorelease];

  // You can set the title of the navigationItem of the controller here, if you want.

  // Optional: display some html briefly before the sign-in page loads
  NSString *html = @"<html><body bgcolor=silver><div align=center>Loading sign-in page...</div></body></html>";
  [viewController setInitialHTMLString:html];

  [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

This is code from OAuthSampleTouch example in the class "OAuthSampleRootViewControllerTouch.m" Please check it. What is the scope and from where I need to pass credentials. If I run this I am getting the log as  Authentication error:

Please help me, I am trying it from three days.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you,
Madan Mohan.

Answer (score 0):

Search for this method

- (GDataServiceGoogleContact *)contactService

Here you will be giving username and password for google account..